# How i can fetch data using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

i has 3 table in database .. the first table for login info, second table for the books and third table has user_id and book_id (foreign key).
when specific user enter his name and password i wand display what the book he has. whats the wrong in my code.. he just implement isAuthenticated and it work .. but he did not display the books why?

this function for login

```
public function isAuthenticated()
{
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM loginUser WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);

    $statment->execute(
        array(
            ':username' => $this->username,
            ':password' => $this->Password
        ));
    $result = $statment->fetchColumn();

    $this->isAuthenticated= ($result == "1");
    return $this->isAuthenticated;
}
```

and this function to fetch the book

```
public function getBooks()
{
    //SELECT loginUser.username, Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username="loay";
    $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=':username'";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute();
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();
    $this->isAuthenticated= ($result == "1");

    foreach($result as $row){
        echo $row['nameOfBook'] . "<br/>";
    }
    return $this->isAuthenticated;
}
```

and here i create object from class in index.php

```
<?php
include_once('User.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"];

    $object = new User();
    $object->username= $username;
    $object->Password=$password;

    if( $object->isAuthenticated() ){
        echo "User Verified";
        $object->getBooks();
    }
    else{
      echo "Wrong User Name Or Password";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: When you connect to your database, you should also set: `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`. That will make PDO thow an exception when a query goes haywire and makes it easier to debug.

Comment: The SQL query in `getBooks()` is probably not doing what you expect. Do you have direct access to MySQL? Can you run this query in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Btw, the line `$this->isAuthenticated= ($result == "1");` in the `getBooks()` method makes no sense. Why would the result of the books query affect the authentication?

Comment: yes i run it in phpmyadmin and its work

Comment: In your getBooks query, you have `loginUser.username=':username'`. Since you have quotes around the placeholder, it will search for a user that's literally called `:username`. Remove the quotes and pass the username in the `->execute()`-method call.

Comment: When you got it to run on phpmyadmin, what did you do with the `:username` placeholder? How does PHP know to do that same thing?

Comment: loginUser.username='Husam'

Comment: and he get the book that husam take it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the placeholder in the query for `getBooks()` wrong:

```
loginUser.username=':username'
```

Since you have quotes around the placeholder, it will search for a user that's literally called `:username`. It should be:

```
loginUser.username = :username
```

Then you need to pass the username when you execute the query (like you do for the login):

```
$statment->execute([
    ':username' => $this->username
]);
```

***Suggestion:*** I would remove the `this->isAuthenticated= ($result == "1");`-line from that method, since it doesn't make any sense in that context. The books query shouldn't affect the authentication. Or rather, you can't even do that query without an authenticated user.

Comment: @husamalmasri - Feel free to accept the answer to tell other users that the issue is resolved.